# Mapnik Initialization does not work

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, style, mapnik, ubuntu

I create geodatabase "training"

```
sudo su
su postgres
createdb -E UTF8 template_postgis2
createlang -d template_postgis2 plpgsql
psql -d postgres -c "UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate='true' WHERE datname='template_postgis2'"
psql -d template_postgis2 -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/contrib/postgis-2.1/postgis.sql
psql -d template_postgis2 -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/contrib/postgis-2.1/rtpostgis.sql
psql -d template_postgis2 -c "GRANT ALL ON geometry_columns TO PUBLIC;"
psql -d template_postgis2 -c "GRANT ALL ON geography_columns TO PUBLIC;"
psql -d template_postgis2 -c "GRANT ALL ON spatial_ref_sys TO PUBLIC;"
createdb training -T template_postgis2
```

[geodatabase training http://savepic.su/3233935.jpg](http://savepic.su/3233935.jpg)

Then I changed "default.style"

```
sudo cp "./default.style" "/usr/share/osm2pgsql/default.style"
```

Then I load shapes

```
sudo apt-get install subversion 
mkdir "/home/oleg/mapnik"
svn co "http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/rendering/mapnik" "/home/oleg/mapnik"
bash /home/oleg/mapnik/get-coastlines.sh
```

Now I want create style

```
python /home/oleg/mapnik/generate_xml.py osm.xml my_osm.xml --dbname training --user postgres --password postgres --accept-none
```

[link http://savepic.su/3233934.jpg](http://savepic.su/3233934.jpg)

Please, tell me how create style.

***Update:*** Now I have this problem.

```
oleg@oleg-pkvb:~/mapnik$ ./generate_xml.py osm.xml osm_new.xml --dbname training --user osm --world_boundaries /home/oleg/world_boundaries/ --accept-none
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./generate_xml.py", line 204, in <module>
serialize(template_xml,options)
  File "./generate_xml.py", line 80, in serialize
mapnik.load_map(m,xml,True)
RuntimeError: Postgis Plugin: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "osm"

Connection string: ' dbname=training user=osm connect_timeout=4'
  encountered during parsing of layer 'landcover' in Layer at line 341 of 'osm.xml'
```

***Update 2:***

```
oleg@oleg-pkvb:~/mapnik$ ./generate_xml.py osm.xml osm_new.xml --dbname training --host localhost --port 5432 --user osm --password postgres --world_boundaries /home/oleg/world_boundaries/ --accept-none
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./generate_xml.py", line 204, in <module>
    serialize(template_xml,options)
  File "./generate_xml.py", line 80, in serialize
    mapnik.load_map(m,xml,True)
RuntimeError: ERROR:  relation "planet_osm_polygon" does not exist
```

***Update 3***

I try download data in my database "training"

```
oleg@oleg-pkvb:~$ sudo osm2pgsql -U osm -d training -W postgres -H localhost -P 5432 Moscow.osm.gz
osm2pgsql SVN version 0.70.5

Password:
Using projection SRS 900913 (Spherical Mercator)
Setting up table: planet_osm_point
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point_tmp" does not exist, skipping
PREPARE get_way (int4) AS SELECT AsText(way) FROM planet_osm_point WHERE osm_id = $1;
 failed: ERROR:  function astext(geometry) does not exist
LINE 1: PREPARE get_way (int4) AS SELECT AsText(way) FROM planet_osm...
                                     ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Error occurred, cleaning up
```

***Update 4:***

Now I use osm2pgsql 0.83, postgis 2.1, postgres 9.1, mapnik 300000. I create user 'gisuser' and database 'gis'. But I have the same problem ((

```
postgres=# ALTER USER gisuser WITH PASSWORD 'postgres';
ALTER ROLE
postgres=# \q
oleg@oleg-pkvb:~$ sudo osm2pgsql -U gisuser -W postgres -d gis -H localhost -P 5432 Moscow.osm.gz
osm2pgsql SVN version 0.83.0 (64bit id space)

Password:
Warning: program compiled against libxml 209 using older 207
Using projection SRS 900913 (Spherical Mercator)
Setting up table: planet_osm_point
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point_tmp" does not exist, skipping
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('planet_osm_point', 'way', 900913, 'POINT', 2 );
 failed: ERROR:  AddGeometryColumn() - invalid SRID
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT AddGeometryColumn('','',$1,$2,$3,$4,$5, $6)"
PL/pgSQL function "addgeometrycolumn" line 5 at SQL statement
```

Comment: You have to run these commands once before using osm2pgsl: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PostGIS/Installation#Activate_PostGIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to poulate your database with osm2pgsql before you can render anything with the official style sheets.

The shapes are necessary for lower zoom levels, but the style expects the tables with the other data too. These are created by osm2pgsql.

**EDIT**

You have to run these commands once before using osm2pgsl: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PostGIS/Installation#Activate_PostGIS

Make sure you have the sql-files for the right Postgis version, and a current version of osm2pgsql. The SVN version might be outdated.

Current osm2pgsql version `0.83` is on github: https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql or the relevant PPA/RPM/...

Comment: `psql -d template_postgis2 -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/contrib/postgis-2.1/postgis.sql
psql -d template_postgis2 -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/contrib/postgis-2.1/rtpostgis.sql
psql -d template_postgis2 -c "GRANT ALL ON geometry_columns TO PUBLIC;"
psql -d template_postgis2 -c "GRANT ALL ON geography_columns TO PUBLIC;"
psql -d template_postgis2 -c "GRANT ALL ON spatial_ref_sys TO PUBLIC;"
createdb training -T template_postgis2`

I create template than I create database. Is it right?

Comment: I did it always the way the wiki says: Create db, then start the sql's on that. I never used templates.